# Angular2 index.html duplicates the googlemap script

Tags: angular, google-maps

I want to use the angular2-google-place-autocomplete library in angular2.
I am loading the library in the index.html but after building the script is duplicated in my html and causes this issue.

**You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.**

Here is my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Proxistore for Media Agency</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/lock/11.4.0/lock.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@salesforce-ux/design-system/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=angular2GoogleMapsLazyMapsAPILoader&key=xxxx;libraries=places"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="./styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="pace-done mini-navbar">
  <app>Loading...</app>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Don't post your API key

Answer (score 0):

Remove the map script block as agm already and autocomplete already call this script. You simply need to declare it once in your app module as root like described here : https://angular-maps.com/

```
@NgModule 
AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: 'YOUR_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY'
    })
```